# Valgrind leak and Segmentation Error with a specific output when trying to malloc

Tags: c, list, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind

So I have a program that receives as input a string with the format `a word1 word2 word3` and that inserts these words into a structure that finally goes into a linked list. With all the inputs I have tried it works perfectly and there are no memory leaks but with this specific output I get a `Segmentation Error` as well as memory leak and it's almost surely because of the length of `word1`.
This is the input: 
`a
Adolph_Blaine_Charles_David_Earl_Frederick_Gerald_Hubert_Irvin_John_Kenneth_Lloyd_Martin_Nero_Oliver_Paul_Quincy_Randolph_Sherman_Thomas_Uncas_Victor_William_Xerxes_Yancy_Zeus_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorffwelchevoralternwarengewissenhaftschaferswessenschafewarenwohlgepflegeundsorgfaltigkeitbeschutzenvorangreifendurchihrraubgierigfeindewelchevoralternzwolfhunderttausendjahresvorandieerscheinenvonderersteerdemenschderraumschiffgenachtmittungsteinundsiebeniridiumelektrischmotorsgebrauchlichtalsseinursprungvonkraftgestartseinlangefahrthinzwischensternartigraumaufdersuchennachbarschaftdersternwelchegehabtbewohnbarplanetenkreisedrehensichundwohinderneuerassevonverstandigmenschlichkeitkonntefortpflanzenundsicherfreuenanlebenslanglichfreudeundruhemitnichteinfurchtvorangreifenvorandererintelligentgeschopfsvonhinzwischensternartigraum foo@bar.zp 2`

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXINPUT 682

typedef struct words {
    char *word1;
    char *word2;
    char *word3;
} words;

typedef struct node{
    words cont;
    struct node *next;
} node;
typedef node *link;

link head;

void add(char c[]) {
    words x;
    char *str;
    link temp = (link)malloc(sizeof(node));
    strtok(c, " ");
    str = strtok(NULL, " ");
    x.word1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
    strcpy(x.word1, str);
    str = strtok(NULL, " ");
    x.word2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1)); /* where the error happens with this input */
    strcpy(x.word2, str);
    str = strtok(NULL, "\0");
    x.word3 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
    strcpy(x.word3, str);
    temp->cont = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

int main() {
    char input[MAXINPUT] = " ";
    head = NULL;
    while (input[0] != 'x') {
        fgets(input, MAXINPUT, stdin);
        input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0;
        if (input[0] == 'a')
            add(input);
        ...
```

When I run this input with this code I get a `Segmentation Error` and valgrind says that there are 3 allocs and only one free and and that the leak\error happens in the line mentioned in the code, specifically with the strlen. It also says I can't access the memory position 0x0 for some reason. I wanted to know why this happens, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not test if `strtok` did find all the tokens. You must check the pointer returned by `strtok()` before using it. If you don't, invalid input will cause undefined behavior.

In your case, the input is longer than 682 bytes, the first 681 bytes are read into the array and this fragment does not contain enough tokens, making one of the `strtok()` calls to return `NULL`, causing undefined behavior when you dereference this null pointer with `strlen()`.

Always test and report error conditions, you will save yourself countless hours of debugging time.

When the program crashes, the memory leaks reported by valgrind are meaningless because the program did not complete its normal execution and of course did not free allocated memory properly.  The memory is still returned to the operating system after program exit, but valgrind reports the blocks that have not been freed by calling `free()`.

To avoid setting an arbitrary limit to the line length, you can use the [POSIX standard function `getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) that re-allocates the array as needed.

You should also use `strdup` to allocate copies of the strings in a single function call:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct words {
    char *word1;
    char *word2;
    char *word3;
} words;

typedef struct node{
    words cont;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef node *link;  // hiding pointers behind typedefs is not recommended

link head;

link add(char c[]) {
    words x = { NULL, NULL, NULL };
    char *str;
    link temp;

    if (strtok(c, " ") != NULL
    &&  (str = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL
    &&  (x.word1 = strdup(str)) != NULL
    &&  (str = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL
    &&  (x.word2 = strdup(str)) != NULL
    &&  (str = strtok(NULL, "")) != NULL
    &&  (x.word3 = strdup(str)) != NULL
    &&  (temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)) != NULL) {
        temp->cont = x;
        temp->next = head;
        return head = temp;
    } else {
        free(x.word3);
        free(x.word2);
        free(x.word1);
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *input = NULL;
    size_t input_size = 0;

    head = NULL;
    while (getline(&input, &input_size, stdin) >= 0 && *input != 'x') {
        input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = '\0';
        if (*input == 'a')
            add(input);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    free(input);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the OP never accepted an answer up to now ... May be propose to the OP to use `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` rather than _fgets_ to remove the limit ? (using _valgrind_ he probably uses a compiler conform to POSIX )